# php DomDocument->saveHTML removes slash

Tags: php, domdocument

Just the part that confuses me:

```
<?php
echo "Start\n";
$newdoc = new DOMDocument();
$newdoc->loadHTML("<script>document.write('</scr' + 'ipt>');</script>");    
echo $newdoc->saveHTML();
echo "\nDone\n";
```

It will output:

```
<script>document.write('' + 'ipt>');</script>
```

Why does it do that and how can I avoid it?

Answer (score 1):

You have to escape the slash:

`$newdoc->loadHTML("<script>document.write('<\/scr' + 'ipt>');</script>");`

Comment: Backslash remains in the results.

Comment: @revo what do you aim to achieve with this exactly?

Comment: I'm not going to achieve something but you should have noted what I already commented. Also you can't do such escaping within a large HTML input so it's totally a temporary solution.

Comment: @revo I thought your comment was from the author of the question so I was wondering why is he doing this. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: No problem @TheFallen

Comment: @TheFallen Creating a template for eBay for a customer. eBay doesn't like the inclusion of external js files, but if you write the stuff in within a <script> tag, it works. Unless ebay finds the full string being printed (hence the splitting of the string.
The system that sends the data to eBay uses the domdocument object and "destroys" the first string.

My workaround is to have the '/' single (so my current code uses:

    write('<'+'/'+'scr'+'ipt>')

That works for some reason.
My question here is to understand why it happens.